# Running nUnit tests for .NET Core in Rider

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, rider

It might be a simple question, but it seems I can't figure out how to combine NUnit and a .NET Core project in Rider.

It is nowhere in the templates and if I just create a simple class library and reference a NuGet package I guess that is not the option. None of the usual NUnit items are recognized even if I reference using NUnit.Framework just like it is referenced in the usual .NET.

Either I don't know something or it is not yet supported. Has anyone had any experience in using NUnit with .NET Core in JetBrains' Rider IDE?

I know there is [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) and [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) available, but I am really used to NUnit, so I really want to make sure there isn't any workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is how I did it thanks to the article *[.NET Standard and .NET Core unit tests not discovered with new .csproj format in Visual Studio 2017](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464912#comment=27-2312068)* .

1. Create an empty .NET Core Class Library
2. Unload the project
3. Edit the .csproj file. For some reason it points to target `netstandard2.0`. Set it to point to `netcoreapp2.0`.
4. Download NuGet Packages

   - NUnit 3.9.0
   - nUnit3TetAdapter
   - Microsoft.Net.Test.SDK
5. Reference your the .NET Core project you want to test in the dependencies
6. Start testing using NUnit.Framework;

Comment: In Rider there's no need to unload project before editing csproj. Just focus project in Solution Explorer and press F4.